# How to generate a combined Q object from a list?

Tags: python, django, django-q, django-contenttypes

I have a list of dictionaries with `app_label` and `model` keys that I got from the `ContentType` model:

```
model_list = [
    {
        'app_label': 'store',
        'model': 'product',
    },
    {
        'app_label': 'store',
        'model': 'profile',
    },
]
```

I need to generate a set of combined [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) from this to use as a [`ForeignKey.limit_choices_to` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to). This is the output I need:

```
limit = Q(app_label = 'store', model = 'product') | Q(app_label = 'store', model = 'profile')
```

So I can use it in a model like this:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to = limit)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    # ...
```

Anyone know how to create a list of combined `Q` objects with the `|` operator by looping through this list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_) (or `lambda a, b: a | b`):

```
limit = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**condition) for condition in model_list))
```

Comment: Why can't we use `|` instead of `operator.or_`?

Comment: @mu無, `|` requires operands (It's an oeprator, not a function like `oeprator.or_`). You need to wrap it in a `lambda` to use it.

Comment: @mu無, In other word, you can't pass an operator without calling it while you can pass functions without calling it